# Highcharts add a new data point

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to update the highchart line graph say every minute. something like shown in this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series/) 
Right now, I use a periodic javascript call to the function that draws the graph. The problem is that it starts to draw it from beginning. 
Is it possible to just add the new data point to the existing line?

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?    filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Exchange rate'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillColor: {
                    linearGradient: {
                        x1: 0,
                        y1: 0,
                        x2: 0,
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops: [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                marker: {
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        lineWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                threshold: null
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'area',
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: data
        }]
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use the `addPoint` function in the data series...

here is an example of a chart that updates every second

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/