# Updating regression by adding new point to scatter plot (Highcharter R)

Tags: r, highcharts, regression, interactive, r-highcharter

I've gotten so far that I can add new points to the scatter plot with a mouse click. Unfortunately, this does not result in an update of the plot and the regression is not recalculated. Is there a way to store the new data point in the existing data and calculate the regression afterwards?

My previous code in highcharter R:

```
library(highcharter)

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(
    type = "scatter",
    margin = list(70, 50, 60, 80),
    events = list(
      click = JS("function(e) {
                  // find the clicked values and the series
                  var x = Math.round(e.xAxis[0].value),
                      y = Math.round(e.yAxis[0].value);

                  // Add it
                  this.series[0].addPoint([x, y]);
                 }")
      )
    ) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(
    gridLineWidth = 1,
    minPadding = 0.2,
    maxPadding = 0.2,
    maxZoom = 60
  ) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(
    title = list(text = "Value"),
    minPadding = 0.2,
    maxPadding = 0.2,
    maxZoom = 60
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_series(
    data = list(c(20, 20), c(80, 80), c(50, 40), c(20, 30)),
    regression = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  hc_add_dependency("plugins/highcharts-regression.js")
```

Comment: Hi @YannickDiehl, welcome to SO! Can you edit this so it is fully reproducible, with calls to "library" and a minimal data example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hello, thank you very much! Of course I can also add the library command, but for my example it only needs the "highcharter" package. This allows the code to be executed reproducibly, since I have stored a data basis in the hc_add_series function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highcharts add a new data point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39474845/highcharts-add-a-new-data-point)